# Extract specific directories with all subdirectories from a tar file

Tags: tar

I know how to extract single file from a tarball, although now I have 500 GB `tar` file without any compression, just a plain `tar` and I would like to extract specifically 3 directories, with such structure:

```
dir1/subDir1/
dir2/subDir2/
dir3/subDir3/subSubDir3/
```

There are many subdirectories inside each of those and real many files. I wish to simply extract everything inside of those.

I am curious as to how to do this, without having to extract the whole tarball.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tar` extracts directories like files, see the [`man page`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tar) for more info.

```
# -v; verbose parameter is rather obstructive
#     in case of thousands and thousands of files

tar -xf archive.tar directory/
```

Comment: I have tested and `tar -xvzf keys/ssl/nginx/ssl-0.0.0-development.tgz -C keys/ssl/nginx package/`  dit extract a directory named `package` within `keys/ssl/nginx`. That does not work, the root of the tar is still extracted with this synthax

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `--strip-components=n` option.

```
tar -xvf archive.tar --strip-components=4
```

> `--strip-components=NUMBER`
>
> ```
> strip NUMBER leading components from file names on extraction
> ```